# Monitor in my java program gets into a deadlock

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

I'm trying to solve single consumer/producer problem using monitor in Java, and the code is as follows. When I run this code, it will finally get stucked. The most typical case is that the consumer calls `wait()`, and then the producer keeps producing but cannot notify the consumer (although it will call `notify()`). I don't know why it's happening. Java code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Monitor {
    int length;
    int size;
    int begin, end;
    int queue[];
    private static Random randGenerator;
    public Monitor() {}
    public Monitor(int length) {
        this.length = length;
        this.size = 0;
        begin = end = 0;
        queue = new int[length];
        randGenerator = new Random(10);
    }
    public synchronized void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        while(size == length) {
            System.out.println("Producer waiting");
            wait();
        }
        int produced = randGenerator.nextInt();
        size++;
        queue[end] = produced;
        end = (end + 1) % length;
        System.out.println("Produce element " + produced + " size "+size);
        // When size is not 1, no thread is blocked and therefore don't need to notify
        if(size == 1) {
            System.out.println("Notify consumer");
            notify();
        }
    }
    public synchronized void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        while(size == 0) {
            System.out.println("Consumer waiting, size " + size);
            wait();
        }
        size--;
        System.out.println("Consume element " + queue[begin] + " size " + size);
        begin = (begin + 1) % length;
        if(size == length - 1) {
            System.out.println("Notify producer");
            notify();
        }
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
    Monitor producer;
    public Producer(Monitor m) {
        producer = m;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        producer = new Monitor();
        System.out.println("Producer created");
        try {
            while(true) {
                producer.produce();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Monitor consumer;
    public Consumer(Monitor m) {
        consumer = m;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Consumer created");
        consumer = new Monitor();
        try {
            while(true) {
                consumer.consume();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class monitorTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Monitor monitor = new Monitor(10);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Producer(monitor));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Consumer(monitor));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Suppose, 2 consumers come first, both enter `wait()`. Then a producer comes, issues one `notify()`. Immediately afterwards, before any consumer is woken, another producer comes, adds an item, but without any notifications. Now, only one consumer will be woken.

Comment: @ZhongYu Thanks for your comment. I create only one producer and one consumer in main function, and the program still cannot run normally. Why is that? Note that I have mentioned the program is targeted for single producer/consumer problem.

Comment: You should not have called `new Monitor()` again - just use the monitor created in main()

Comment: @ZhongYu After deleting these two lines it works fine. Thanks!!! (what a silly mistake for me lol). Since you didn't post an answer (no need indeed...), I'll mark anacron's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the control of each thread enters the `produce()` or `consume()` methods, the size and length are both zero and hence both threads are waiting for the other to notify. Break this and your code will come out of the deadlock.

```
public synchronized void produce() throws InterruptedException {
    while(size == length) { // size is 0 and length is 0; so wait
        System.out.println("Producer waiting");
        wait();
    }
```

---

```
public synchronized void consume() throws InterruptedException {
    while(size == 0) { // size is 0 so wait
        System.out.println("Consumer waiting, size " + size);
        wait();
    }
```

---

This is happening because you have a default constructor which you are calling inside the `run()` method of your Producer and Consumer objects.

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
    Monitor producer;
    public Producer(Monitor m) {
        producer = m;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        producer = new Monitor(); // REMOVE THIS

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Monitor consumer;
    public Consumer(Monitor m) {
        consumer = m;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Consumer created");
        consumer = new Monitor(); // AND REMOVE THIS
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: But I do initialize monitor.length to be 10(`Monitor monitor = new Monitor(10)`), so length should not be 0 but 10. Am I wrong?

Comment: I printed the size and length before the beginning of the `while` statement. I got size = 0 and length = 0.